# How find this bmatrix is inverse $A^{-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $$A_{ij}=\dfrac{1}{n}\min{\{i,j\}},$$
that is
$$A=\dfrac{1}{n}\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&\ddots&1&1\\
1&2&2&\ddots&\ddots&2\\
1&2&3&3&\ddots&3\\
\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\cdots\\
1&\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&n-1&n-1\\
1&2&\cdots&\cdots&n-1&n
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Find $A^{-1}$.

I find
$$A^{-1}=n\begin{bmatrix}
2&-1\\
-1&2&-1\\
0&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots\\
\vdots&\cdots&-1&2&-1\\
0&\cdots&\cdots&-1&2
\end{bmatrix}.$$
But my book states
[image]

Is my answer wrong or the book is wrong?
if my answer is wrong,How find this $A^{-1}$, Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1):

The bottom right entry of $I=AA^{-1}$ is the last row of $A$ times the last column of $A^{-1}$. It seems that your answer is wrong.

Comment: ah, that's meaning my answer is wrong? and How find this $A^{-1}$,Thank you

Comment: Yeah, and How find this question $A^{-1}$?

Comment: @math110 The easiest way is to try a few small examples, $\color{red}{\text{learn the pattern}}$, $\color{green}{\text{make a guess}}$ on the form of $A^{−1}$ and verify that $AA^{−1}$ is indeed equal to $I$. This is called *[induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_reasoning)* (not to be confused with *[mathematical induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction)*).

Comment: I think you have Misunderstood what I mean, I say Now How find this  book's  answer.Thank you,

Comment: @math110 I haven't misunderstood your question, but perhaps you don't understand my comment. To find $A^{-1}$, you establish a conjecture by *induction*; to prove that this conjecture is correct, you may directly *verify* that $AA^{-1}=I$ for this alleged $A^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you ,I have solve it.